# null values keep appearing

Tags: java, arrays, null

I want to merge 2 Stirng arrays
the first one is merged okay but the second one keeps having null values even though it isn't empty
no errors just wrong values
what is the problem here?

```
public class Q4 {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String array1[] = new String[]{"Ahmad", "Adam"};
        String array2[] = new String[]{"Mick", "Ali"};
        int n1 = array1.length;
        int n2 = array2.length;
        String []array3 = new String[n1+n2];

        for(int i = 0; i < n1; i++)
            array3[i] = array1[i];

        for(int i = n1; i<n2; i++) {
            int j = 0;
            array3[i] = array2[j++];
        }

        for(int i = 0; i<array3.length; i++)
            System.out.print(array3[i] + " ");
    }
}
```

the output should be

> Ahmad Adam Mick Ali

but this is what I get

> Ahmad Adam null null

Comment: Please take the time to format the code you're presenting in Stack Overflow questions. Think about how you'd want the code to look if *you* were reading it.

Comment: I'd also strongly recommend using braces for *all* `for` loop bodies, even if they're only single statements. Fundamentally though, I strongly suspect you should step through the code in a debugger, work out what values of `i` and `j` you *expect* to be used, and what actually happens. (Basically, your middle `for` loop is broken in terms of both its bounds and its use of `j`.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your Second loop's i value is n1 size(2).and loop will continue before n2 size(2).that's why value not added.

Solution: U need add value after 1st array. If you will Store value from 1st array size ,then it will store value perfectly.

```
public class Q4 {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String array1[] = new String[]{"Ahmad", "Adam"};
        String array2[] = new String[]{"Mick", "Ali"};
        int n1 = array1.length;
        int n2 = array2.length;
        String []array3 = new String[n1+n2];

        for(int i = 0; i < n1; i++){
            array3[i] = array1[i];
        }

        for(int i = 0; i<n2; i++) {
            array3[n1++] = array2[i];
        }

        for(int i = 0; i<array3.length; i++)
            System.out.print(array3[i] + " ");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i = n1; i<n2; i++) {
```

the condition inside the second for loop is wrong.
As it is now you are starting from size of first array (2) to size of second array (2)

what you want should be

```
for(int i = n1; i<n2+n1; i++) {
```

also you are declaring `int j` inside the for loop which means j is reset each loop, move its definition outside of the loop or better yet replace it with

`i-n1`

Comment: I did. "move its definition outside of the loop"

Answer (score 0):

In the second for loop I should've used i<array3.length instead of i<n2
since i=n1 and n2=n1 so for loop wasn't even excuted